# What is the smallest anti-virus software for use on Windows NT machines?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, lightweight

I have some really old machines and want to run a virus scan on them. They only have about 64mb RAM, 333Mhz processor, etc. I don't want a whole suite, just something light weight and effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows 98 and upwards you could try [Clamwin](http://www.clamwin.com/). Note that is does not do on-access scanning.  You need to manually or schedule a scan of your drives.

Comment: Seconding the clamwin suggestion. I run it on some old p2 machines just fine.

Comment: I am going to use the portable version. it's only 6MB (27MB installed).

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I vote for "Don't give the user Administrator rights", "Apply current security fixes", and "Don't run unnecessary services or software" for a low-impact anti-virus solution.

Comment: these aren't user computers, the owners only allow "system changes" rarely, and they don't run unnecessary software.

Answer (score 1):

dr.web seems to be so.

Comment: what version friend?

Comment: 4 i think

Comment: indeed. Just checked the docs - both 4.44 and 5.0 should work just fine with 64 MB RAM